# Concatenated PHP file names in URL, MVC architecture

Tags: php, html, url, model-view-controller, controller

I'm fairly new to PHP and am designing a login system ideally according to the MVC pattern, I have a front controller that is called whenever a form is submitted (e.g. from loginView.php), and a corresponding controller for each view that the front controller calls:

`<form action="frontController.php/login" method="post" class="container">`

the front controller code:

`$uri = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);`

```
    case "/url/frontController.php/login":
        $loginCont = new loginController();
```

however whenever a form is submitted the url shown is `url/frontController.php/loginView.php`, I was wondering what is going wrong with the code, any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: you are using .htaccess ?

Comment: @ahmadMarafa nope